# Avoid White Background when sliding animation

Tags: java, android, animation

i'm ne in android, i make an animation by override setContentView in one activity (only one activity). i try this one and it work :

```
@Override
public void setContentView(int layoutResID) {
    LayoutInflater inflator=getLayoutInflater();
    View view=inflator.inflate(layoutResID, null, false);
    view.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, android.R.anim.slide_in_left));
    super.setContentView(view);
}
```

the problem is when the animation run, there a white background. how to avoid the white background (i want to show the current view instead of white background when the animation run).

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you're trying to do is animate the activity coming in you should use [overridePendingTransition](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#overridePendingTransition%28int,%20int%29). This is the standard way of changing the animation that an activity will use when being started. You might also want to set the theme of your activity to "@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" in your manifest to remove any unwanted window background from messing with your animation.

Comment: there only one activity. not 2. so i need to make animation when i call setCOntentView() in one activity, i try this one but not work : 

    
@Override
 public void setContentView(int layoutResID) {
  
  LayoutInflater inflator=getLayoutInflater();
  View view=inflator.inflate(layoutResID, null, false);
  if(the_anim!=null) view.startAnimation(the_anim);
  overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.slide_in_left, android.R.anim.slide_out_right);
  super.setContentView(view);
  the_anim=null;
 }